# In spring-kafka how to set up a kafka listener to only receive key and metadata, but without a payload?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is it possible to "tell" Kafka broker to not send the payload of a record at all to the client? I know you can configure the listener to not receive it by not listing as an argument:

```
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "myTopic",
            groupId = "groupId"
    )
    public void listen(
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = true) String key,
            ConsumerRecordMetadata meta)
    {
    }
```

However the performance measurements I did with and without the `@Payload` argument did not differ much, therefore I assume the consumer application is still getting an entire payload over the network, but just not sending it to the method annotated with `@KafkaListener`.

I would only like to get the metadata, including the key.

Comment: You could use `Message` object, then extract key from that, and ignore value, rather than having two parameters

Comment: `org.springframework.messaging.Message`? If so, it contains the payload and I've deliberately used a set of arguments that does not contain a payload.

Comment: Yes. As answered, though, you'll always get the whole payload from Kafka API. Whether Spring decomposes that or not into extra parameters, is a separate issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kafka-clients` API provides no way to avoid the record `value()` being passed over the network.

You can minimize the local overhead by using a `ByteArrayDeserializer` for the value deserializer to avoid performing any transformation after receipt.